# question about the continuity of a function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I need to show that:

If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ iff $f^*(x_0)=f_*(x_0)$ where:
$f^*(x_0)=\lim_{x \to x_0} \sup f(y)=\inf_{\epsilon > 0} \sup_{|y-x_0|<\epsilon}f(y)$ and 
$f_*(x_0)=\lim_{x \to x_0} \inf f(y)=\sup_{\epsilon > 0} \inf_{|y-x_0|<\epsilon}f(y)$

any hints thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then for any $\epsilon>0$, if $x$ is close enough to $x_0$ you will have $f(x_0)-\epsilon \le f(x) \le f(x_0)+ \epsilon$. What does that say about $f_*(x_0)$ and $f^*(x_0)$?

Suppose $f_*(x_0) = f^*(x_0)$ and $\epsilon>0$. We have $f_*(x_0) = f(x_0) =  f^*(x_0)$, of course.
Then for $x$ is close enough to $x_0$  you have $f(x) \le f^*(x_0)+ \epsilon$ and similarly $f_*(x_0)-\epsilon \le f(x)$. What does this say about $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$?

Comment: you made it easy. THANK YOU!

Comment: Happy it helped!